# Controls lose the index when a PDF file is loaded by form_load event in webBrowser control in C#

Tags: c#, tabcontrol, tabindex, form-load

I have a tabControl on my form in C# windows application that has two tab pages. I disabled the tabIndex of this tabControl. There is a textBox on the first page of this tabControl and a webBrowser on the second page of this tabControl. I want the textBox has the first index by default when form is loading. And this is working very good. But when I add this command:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\help.pdf");
```

on the form_load event, the textBox doesn't have the index anymore. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET WebBrowser control has two events that may help you:

- OnNavigating
- OnDocumentCompleted

The simplest logic would be to persist whether or not the TextBox was focused prior to navigating and to restore the focus state once navigation has finished.

```
    private bool _bWasTextBox1Focused = false;

    private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        _bWasTextBox1Focused = textBox1.Focused;
    }

    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_bWasTextBox1Focused) textBox1.Focus();
    }
```

Comment: Yes you give me the right answer but there is an easier method: I only focused on textBox1 in webBrowser documentComplete event. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I only focused on textBox1 in webBrowser documentComplete event:

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Focus();
}
```